# Ubuntu 20.04: playonlinux office applications overlay all other app windows

Tags: wine, playonlinux, microsoft-office

I have installed MS Office 2016 according to this instructions
https://linustechtips.com/topic/1211957-office-2016-ubuntu-1804-should-also-work-on-2004/

The installation went fine. I'm able to run office applications (Word, Excel, Powerpoint). But the issue is , when running MS Word from playonlinux the word app window is always on the top of all windows. Alt+Tab is working for switching the apps, but the new selected app is always under the word window.

If I resize word fullscreen, I can not switch to any other app because of this.
Can you please help on this topic?

Comment: Even I am facing the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

in PlayOnLinix, go to the program and choose Configure. Then the Wine tab and Configure Wine. In Graphics select "Allow the window manager to control the windows" and Apply. It should work now for this application.